# Jenkins - running a working Scriptler script in a job results in NPE

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I wrote a simple Scriptler script which enables all jobs in a certain view.
When I execute the script in the Scriplter view, it succeeds.
However, when I run it as part of a job (Build, Scriptler script) it fails with a NPE. I understand that it does not identify the Jenkins object.

This is the script:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.instance.getView("VIEW_NAME").items.each { item ->
    println "\nJob: $item.name is enabled"
    item.disabled = false
}
```

And this is the excpetion:

```
Execution of script [enableAutomaticTestsViewJobs.groovy] failed - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getView() on null objectorg.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.util.GroovyScript$ScriptlerExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getView() on null object
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.util.GroovyScript.call(GroovyScript.java:131)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to Channel to /172.23.50.250(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1537)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:822)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.builder.ScriptlerBuilder.perform(ScriptlerBuilder.java:116)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getView() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.util.GroovyScript.call(GroovyScript.java:122)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you passing `Jenkins.instance.getView("VIEW_NAME")` VIEW_NAME here? Hardcoded?

Comment: hard coded, yes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using `Jenkins.instance` use `Hudson.instance`.

```
import hudson.model.*

Hudson.instance.getView("VIEW_NAME").items.each { item ->
   println "\nJob: $item.name is enabled"
   item.disabled = false
}
```

[Use this Groovy File for Reference](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/disableAllJobs.groovy)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is the same result...works via the Scriptler but not via job

Comment: I do think you got [scriptler plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin) installed.

Comment: I got Scriplter version 2.9